# Is there anyway to count the number of forms on a page using Php

Tags: php, forms, count

I was wondering if there is anyway to count the number of forms on a page using any php function, for example using get file contents.

What i would like to find is the sequence number of the form that has been submitted. Like for example, if the second form out of say 5 forms on the page has been submitted using POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to count the number of forms using PHP then yes there is a method in which you can load the DOM in php and count the number of form tags from this link
[domdocument in php](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
specifically at this example [how to get tags by name](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php#Hcom87294)

But a better method at getting sequence would be to add

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "sequence" value = x>
```

where "x" above in the code represents the form number that has been posted. The form number is contained in the variable $_POST["sequence"]

Comment: Or OP should use different "action" attributes for each form, and let every form (and thus action) be handled by a different php script.

Comment: @georoot , am in Mumbai, are you working somewhere ?

Comment: @getroot , ping me back if you interested in working part time from Goa itself for my firm. We make CRM systems for various companies. javascript and php are tools, am sure u are awesome at it :)

Comment: @Manu yeah sure would like to hear about it. My mail is me[at]rahulbhola[dot]in

Comment: @getroot , sure, will get in touch with you at the earliest, Goodnight